# How to show menu item as action on a toolbar in a fragment

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, menu

I have setup a basic menu and a toolbar like so:

`home_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/_ui_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_active"
        />


</menu>
```

`fragment_home.xml` <-This is where I want to show the toolbar and menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="._fragments.dash.HomeFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/app_logo_new"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:padding="16dp"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`HomeFragment.kt` <- This is the fragment where I've setup the toolbar

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        appToolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.homeToolbar)
        appToolbar.title = ""
        appToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.home_menu)
        appToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener{
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.notifications -> {
                    Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    true
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d("Menu", "Terrible things have happened in menu")
                    false
                }
            }

        }

        return view
    }

}
```

With this simple setup, I was able to get the toolbar working. Also clicking on the *menu item "Notifications"* gives out a toast as expected.

However, the menu is being displayed as a drop-down menu like so:

[image: menu_kt]

How do I make it into an action?

**Edit:**

- I have disabled the default Action bar in themes by using the property `.NoActionBar`
  -

Comment: how you want to show like drop down or on action bar?

Comment: I want an icon of the notification button. Not drop-down

Comment: you can change by setting showAsAction value to "ifRoom" in your menu item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the native `Toolbar` in your layout; i.e., `<Toolbar>`. That's ignoring the `app:showAsAction` attribute in your menu XML, as it's in your app's namespace.

I would guess that you actually meant to use the library `Toolbar`, in which case you'd want to change that layout element to `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>`, and to modify the relevant `import` statement in your `HomeFragment` class.

If you actually did mean to use the native `Toolbar`, for some reason, then you need to use the `showAsAction` attribute in the `android` namespace; i.e., `android:showAsAction`.